# .htaccess Not Working as Expected

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http, rewrite

I have a hosted account not linked to any domain at /~me.

In the top level of my home directory I have a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule 123.html cgi-bin/example.php [nc]
```

The full path of example.php is /~me/public_html/cgi-bin/example.php. However /~me/123.html returns a 404.

Is my .htaccess not valid?

Comment: `/~me/public_html/cgi-bin/example.php contains the above file` - what do you mean?  Where's the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: "in the top level of my home directory" - /~me. The full path of file cgi-bin/example.php is at /~me/public_html/cgi-bin/example.php.

Comment: Which directory is your document root - `~me` or `~me/public_html`?

Comment: /~me but it's a pretty standard hosting idea that web requests get redirected to public_html. The .htaccess file in ~me should still work. That's how it works in my other host provider for example.

Comment: Well, if you put a `test.html` file in `~me`, not in `public_html`, does it work?

Comment: No - you'd have to put it in public_html for it to be served up by apache.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the [shared hosts Apache mod_rewrite config](http://transmissionboards.com/tech/htaccess-not-finding-redirect-scripts-shared-hosting-t253.html) that identifies which script to run by the host. I wasn't using a hostname initially, just raw IP, so the server didn't which user account directory to find the target script in.